# Connecting to database via php code

Tags: php, mysql

I am programming a game in PHP and have the following code to connect to a database

```
//$sqldb=mysql_connect('godaddy.hostedresource.com', 'godaddyUserName', 'godaddyPassword') OR die ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
$sqldb=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword') OR die ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
```

The trick here is that if I am on the production server I comment out the godaddy database; when I upload the code to the server I then comment out the localhost code instead.

Unfortunately the ineveitable has happened and I uploaded the code with the wrong connection commented out; this led to 24 hours of locked out customers! :(

Is there a way to have the code to tell if it is on the localhost server, and if it isn't it then looks for the godaddy connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this to identify if its on live or localhost

```
if($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] == "localhost" 
    && 
   $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == "127.0.0.1"){
  // in localhost
  $hostname = "localhost";
  $username = "localuser";
  $password = "localpassword";
}else{
  // not in localhost
 $hostname = "livehost";
 $username = "liveuser";
 $password = "livepassword";
}
```

and fail if couldn't connect to database but save the error into a file.

```
if(!mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password)){
 file_put_contents("mysql_connect.error",mysql_error(),FILE_APPEND);
 die("Couldn't connect to database");
}
```

a suggestion, try not to use mysql_* anymore, switch to PDO or mysqli ..

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'the.name.of.your.devel.server') {
    $host = 'localhost';
} else {
    $host = 'name.of.godaddy.server';
}
$sqldb = mysql_connect($host, ....);
```

Answer (score 0):

i normally use a method of obtaining the URL / domain of the site? This can work in certain situations and setups. Otherwise if your operating with a fixed IP than you can also use this method

Have a look over the methods using $_SERVER

[PHP $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be for you to check your external IP address and see where you are. A solution should present itself by looking at the properties inside the `$_SERVER` global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a good suggestion : You coding a game , game is a big program, you don't use mysql* function directly in big program , because yourself should handling them, such as error handling.i suggest you use a DB-Handler. please google for :  DB-Handler PHP

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned by other people, you can obtain the current site your script is running on using the `$_SERVER` variable. However, I would like to provide an alternative solution.

You could make a folder in your website (both local and production), something like `config`, then store a configuration file in it, for example `config.php`, with the following:

```
<?php
// Local
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'mypassword';
?>
```

And for production:

```
<?php
// Production
$db_host = 'godaddy.hostedresource.com';
$db_username = 'godaddyUserName';
$db_password = 'godaddyPassword';
?>
```

and disallow access to the directory with a `.htaccess` file in the directory, something like:

```
deny from all
```

Then, in your PHP code, do the following:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/config/config.php");
$sqldb=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) OR die ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
?>
```

Now, simply leave the different configuration files where they're at and upload everything else, so your code will access different configuration files whenever it runs.

Also, the `.htaccess` file should prevent anyone from accessing the file via HTTP, and having the file contents in PHP tags, as well as a .php extension should prevent anyone from seeing any contents if they were able to access the file (PHP would parse the file before it is rendered, and would output nothing).